# Getting error while placing order in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

When i try to place order after selecting payment method i am getting error as "An error occured on the server.Please try to place the order agian error". please help how to resolve this.
Error while inspecting in network.

> /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Checkout\Mode\GuestPaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(8dffeA1l6JygGlr...','abc.abc@pr...',
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payme\Interceptor),
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) #1
> /var/www/html/ihouzit/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...',
> A…r.php(26):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array) #11
> /var/www/html/ihouzit/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(137):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>
> ## 12 /var/www/html/ihouzit/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261):
>
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() #13
> /var/www/html/ihouzit/index.php(39):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>
> ## 14 {main}

Comment: Which payment method have you selected while placing the order?

Comment: @sumit. Paygate . Its cuming for all the payment method.

Comment: Any error log for this? Or any thing in the Network tab of your browser?

Comment: @Sumit Updated in question

Comment: Have you tried to place an order with registered customer?

Comment: @Sumit. This i am doing with registered cuystomer only

Comment: @sumit The error is coming for both. registered user and guest as well

Comment: OK, please give me some time, I'll check and let you know if I've something related to this.

Comment: @Sumit Ok sure...

Comment: Magento\Checkout\Mode\GuestPaymentInformationManagement it shold be Magento\Checkout\Model\GuestPaymentInformationManagement

Comment: @Sumit Its model only. Error in copy paste